# SliverFillRemaining with hasScrollBody: true is expanding too much

Tags: flutter

I am using a SliverFillRemaining in a CustomScrollView, and when I scroll all the way down SliverFillRemaining  is expanding to all of the screen, how can I set a limit in the scroll to avoid this behavior?

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange[100 * (index % 12+1)],
              height: 60,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "List Item $index",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 10,
      ),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      hasScrollBody: true,
      fillOverscroll: true,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue[100],
        child: Icon(
          Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied,
          size: 100,
          color: Colors.blue[900],
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

hasScrollBody: true is mandatory for me because when I insert a new element in a list I don't want the scroll position change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try setting `fillOverscroll` to `false`?

Comment: @ClevinoAlrin I already tried it and I am getting the same behavior, thank you so much for you help, let see if we can find an approach, I tried to define a custom `ScrollPhysics` but I couldn't make it work as expected.